# Eclipse Timeout Error from the debugger?

Tags: eclipse, xdebug

I am using Eclipse to develop Android apps.  Things seem to run along smoothly while I'm debugging and then Eclipse seems to hang up - a "Not Responding" error.  I looked in the log files and I get this timeout error every 3 seconds.  Anyone else seen this?

I have to keep restarting my machine.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.debug 4 125 2014-03-12 10:18:19.417
!MESSAGE Internal error logged from JDI Debug: 
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException: Timeout occurred while waiting for packet 12963.
at   org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.PacketReceiveManager.getReply(PacketReceiveManager.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.PacketReceiveManager.getReply(PacketReceiveManager.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.MirrorImpl.requestVM(MirrorImpl.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.MirrorImpl.requestVM(MirrorImpl.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.VirtualMachineImpl.classesBySignature(VirtualMachineImpl.java:638)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.VirtualMachineImpl.classesByName(VirtualMachineImpl.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIDebugTarget.jdiClassesByName(JDIDebugTarget.java:1596)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.hcr.JavaHotCodeReplaceManager.filterUnloadedTypes(JavaHotCodeReplaceManager.java:348)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.hcr.JavaHotCodeReplaceManager.notifyUnsupportedHCR(JavaHotCodeReplaceManager.java:379)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.hcr.JavaHotCodeReplaceManager$2.run(JavaHotCodeReplaceManager.java:322)
at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$AsynchRunner.run(DebugPlugin.java:1068)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$AsynchRunner.async(DebugPlugin.java:1051)
at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin$EventDispatchJob.run(DebugPlugin.java:405)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SESSION 2014-03-12 10:30:21.771 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run -clean, then use Task Manager (in Windows) to stop adb.exe.  Once you do this, things run smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you clean up your eclipse using terminal

Mine directory

```
cd /Applications/eclipse_juno/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Clean command

```
./eclipse -clean
```

OR

Open up eclipse.ini in your eclipse folder.

Change this line

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

into this

```
-Xms768m
-Xmx768m
eclipse.ini

-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-Xms768m
-Xmx768m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

If still happen, restart your machine.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/03/15/your-eclipse-always-crash-how-to-fix-and-enhance-to-do-list/

Comment: I don't want to keep rebooting.

Comment: I did run eclipse -clean.  Then the adb daemon wouldn't connect.  I had to manually shut down adb by running task manager and then restarting eclipse.

Comment: so what happen now? is it fixed?

Comment: It's fixed, but running eclipse -clean introduced more problems.  Otherwise, I would have accepted your answer.  And I don't know that the same thing won't happen again.

Comment: what problems? I can help you

Comment: It happened again, this time eclipse did not respond when I ran -clean.  I had to reboot.

Comment: how long does it take? I executed this command 5 minutes back and its Evaluating extension

Answer (score 4):

You can increase a value of debugging time out in Eclipse.

Go to Window/Preferences. In the Java/Debug you'll see Debugger Time out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Unselect Window->Preferences->Java->Debug, "Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions"

Answer (score 0):

Try this for eclipse

Menu -> Run-> Remove All BreakPoints